# Why are channels supported by my interface different from that permitted for an ad-hoc network?

Tags: networking, wifi, wifi-hotspot, ad-hoc-network

Why are the channels supported for an Ad hoc network ( **12 channels** ) different from those that my interface support ( **35 channels)**

---

- To find the 35 channels, I ran

  ```
  iwlist wlan0 channel
  ```
- to find those accepted for my ad hoc network

  ```
  cat channel_list  | while read i
  do
      echo -n "$i: "
     iwconfig wlan0 channel $i
  done
  ```

I have the following error for channels greated than 12:

```
 Error for wireless request "Set Frequency" (8B04) :
     SET failed on device wlp3s0 ; Invalid argument.
```